Searching a column for a substring that matches a value from another column
let's say I have a table that looks something like this:



Value
Longer_Value
Third_Value
Result




substring
wrong_cell_sorry
wrong_match



othertext
substring_here
match_this1



othertext
secondone_here
match_this2



secondone
substring_there
match_this3




I want to fill in the Result column with values of Third_Value column corresponding to values in the Longer_Value column if the value from the first column was found. If more than one was found, I would like to list them with some delimiter.
So the end table would look something like this:



Value
Longer_Value
Third_Value
Result




substring
wrong_cell_sorry
wrong_match
match_this1, match_this3


othertext
substring_here
match_this1
no_match


othertext
secondone_here
match_this2
no_match


secondone
substring_there
match_this3
match_this2



I've been trying various combinations of .loc and str.contains (with regex disabled) but so far without any luck. Any ideas how to approach this?

Does the below resolve your case?
# Function to find matches and update the Result column
def find_value(row, df):
    matches = df[df['Longer_Value'].str.contains(row['Value'], regex=False)]['Third_Value'].tolist()
    return ', '.join(matches) if matches else 'no_match'

# Apply the function to each row in the DataFrame
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row: find_value(row, df), axis=1)


Thank you so much! That did the trick, I just needed to use the na=False argument in str.contains, because I was getting an error. Quick check of the dataset seems to confirm that the results are correct. Thank you very much.

There is no highly efficient way to do this, you could loop over the unique values and perform a search with str.contains and boolean indexing, then map the keys and optionally replace the '' with 'no_match':
mapper = {v: ', '.join(df.loc[df['Longer_Value'].str.contains(v), 'Third_Value'])
          for v in df['Value'].unique()}

df['Result'] = df['Value'].map(mapper).replace('', 'no_match')

Variant (python ≥ 3.8):
mapper = {v: 'no_match' if (x:=df.loc[df['Longer_Value'].str.contains(v),
                                      'Third_Value']).empty
             else ', '.join(x)
          for v in df['Value'].unique()}

df['Result'] = df['Value'].map(mapper)

Output:
       Value      Longer_Value  Third_Value                    Result
0  substring  wrong_cell_sorry  wrong_match  match_this1, match_this3
1  othertext    substring_here  match_this1                  no_match
2  othertext    secondone_here  match_this2                  no_match
3  secondone   substring_there  match_this3               match_this2

Considering full words instead of substrings
If you want to consider full words, you could also explode and perform a map:
words = (df.assign(Longer_Value=df['Longer_Value'].str.split('_'))
           .explode('Longer_Value')
           .groupby('Longer_Value')['Third_Value'].agg(', '.join)
        )
df['Result'] = df['Value'].map(words).fillna('no_match')

